# Telegram Bot joins count

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, aiogram

How to get the number of joins in a private channel by the link generated by the bot earlier?

I want my bot to be able to get the count of joins by the link or to handle joins by links generated by the bot earlier

I will be grateful for the solution

Answer (score 0):

With the telegram bot api, you need to store the join count by checking for the join request's invite link.

Something like,

if joinrequest.invite_link = Invite_link:
invite_link[count]++

Comment: my channel work without join requests

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).